# How to wait for all images to load from page.evaluate function in puppeteer when the DOM is populated using a client side function

Tags: javascript, node.js, screenshot, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to make the code execution wait for all images to load before **puppeteer** takes a screenshot. My DOM gets populated when initData() function is called, which is defined in the client side js file. Delay or timeout is an option but I am sure there must be a more efficient way of doing it.

```
    (async (dataObj) => {
             const url = dataObj.url;
             const payload = dataObj.payload;
             const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false,devtools:false});
             const page = await browser.newPage();
             await page.goto(url,{'waitUntil': 'networkidle0'});

             await page.evaluate((payload) => {
               initData(payload);
                //initData is a client side function that populates the DOM, need to wait 
                //here till the images are loaded. 
               },payload)

             await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720 })
             await page.screenshot({ path: 'test.png' });
             await browser.close();
    })(dataObj)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but have you considered `window.onload`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[As mentioned in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51652947/8492116), image elements have a `complete` property. You can write a function that returns true when all images in the document have been fetched:

```
function imagesHaveLoaded() { return Array.from(document.images).every((i) => i.complete); }
```

And you can wait for that function like so:

```
await page.waitForFunction(imagesHaveLoaded);
```

Putting the two together with your original code and adding a timeout so it doesn’t wait indefinitely, we get:

```
function imagesHaveLoaded() {
    return Array.from(document.images).every((i) => i.complete);
}

(async (dataObj) => {
         const url = dataObj.url;
         const payload = dataObj.payload;
         const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, devtools: false});
         const page = await browser.newPage();
         await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

         await page.evaluate((payload) => {
           initData(payload);
         }, payload);

         await page.waitForFunction(imagesHaveLoaded, { timeout: YOUR_DESIRED_TIMEOUT });

         await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720 })
         await page.screenshot({ path: 'test.png' });
         await browser.close();
})(dataObj)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works well! Sad that I couldn't think of such a simple thing.

Comment: This is very helpful answer except one thing. `every` function will return false if one of images is not loaded yet. So it should be put in the loop if you need to wait till all images are loaded.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow, @DJ-Glock. `waitForFunction` will keep trying until the function returns `true`, effectively placing the code within a loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using promises, by getting all `<img>` tags on your document and loop check until the browser fetch all of them (when `img.complete == true` for all imgs) then you resolve the promise.

> **HTMLImageElement.complete** Read only
>
> Returns a Boolean that is true if the browser has finished fetching the image, whether successful or not. It also shows true, if the image has no src value.
>
> Ref.: [MDN HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)

I've implemented a function for that, returns a promise that resolves when all imgs are fetched and rejects in case it reaches the timeout (initially 30 seconds but it is changeable).

Usage:

```
// consuming the promise
imgReady().then(
  (imgs) => {
    // do stuff here
    console.log('imgs ready');
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log('imgs taking to long to load');
  }
);

// inside asyng functions
const imgs = await imgReady();
```

> **Note on `window.onload`:** You can use `window.onload` too; however, `window.onload` waits for everything to load instead of only images.

```js
/**
 * @param timeout: how long to wait until reject and cancel the execution.
 * @param tickrate: how long to recheck all imgs again.
 *
 * @returns
 *   A promise which resolve when all img on document gets fetched.
 *   The promise get rejected if it reach the @timeout time to execute.
 */
function imgReady(timeout = 30*1000, tickrate = 10) {
  const imgs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));
  const t0 = new Date().getTime();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const checkImg = () => {
      const t1 = new Date().getTime();

      if (t1 - t0 > timeout) {
        reject({
          message: `CheckImgReadyTimeoutException: imgs taking to loong to load.`
        });
      }

      if (imgs.every(x => x.complete)) {
        resolve(imgs);
      } else {
        setTimeout(checkImg, tickrate);
      }
    };

    checkImg();
  });
}

imgReady().then(console.log,console.error);
```

```css
img{max-width: 100px;}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/ESC_large_ISS022_ISS022-E-11387-edit_01.JPG">
<br>
<img src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/velka/planet-earth-1401465698wt7.jpg">
```

Comment: This is only (a slightly complicated version of) the client-side part of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the brief answer lenilsondc, but I agree with @Aankhen. His answer is a simpler version and does what I require.