# Puppeteer - Wait for network requests to complete after page.select()

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Is there a way to wait for network requests to resolve after performing an action on a page, before performing a new action in Puppeteer?

I need to interact with a select menu on the page using `page.select()` which causes dynamic images and fonts to load into the page. I need to wait for these requests to complete before executing the next action.

--

**Caveats:**

1. I cannot reload the page or go to a new url.
2. I do not know what the request types might be, or how many

--

```
// launch puppeteer
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});

// load new page
const page = await browser.newPage();

// go to URL and wait for initial requests to resolve
await page.goto(pageUrl, {
  waitUntil: "networkidle0"
});

// START LOOP
for (let value of lotsOfValues) {

  // interact with select menu
  await page.select('select', value);

  // wait for network requests to complete (images, fonts)
  ??

  // screenshot page with new content
  await pageElement.screenshot({
    type: "jpeg",
    quality: 100
  });

} // END LOOP

// close
await browser.close();
```

Comment: you can set request interception on and check if every request to (image, fonts) after `page.select` has corresponding response.

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction. I re-wrote this module to do what I wanted - https://www.npmjs.com/package/pending-xhr-puppeteer

Answer (score 9):

The answer to this lies in using `page.setRequestInterception(true);` and monitoring subsequent requests, waiting for them to resvolve before moving on to the next task (**thanks @Guarev** for the point in the right direction).

This module (https://github.com/jtassin/pending-xhr-puppeteer) does exactly that, but for XHR requests. I modified it to look for 'image' and 'font' types.

Final code looks something like this:

```
// launch puppeteer
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});

// load new page
const page = await browser.newPage();

// go to URL and wait for initial requests to resolve
await page.goto(pageUrl, {
  waitUntil: "networkidle0"
});

// enable this here because we don't want to watch the initial page asset requests (which page.goto above triggers) 
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

// custom version of pending-xhr-puppeteer module
let monitorRequests = new PuppeteerNetworkMonitor(page);

// START LOOP
for (let value of lotsOfValues) {

  // interact with select menu
  await page.select('select', value);

  // wait for network requests to complete (images, fonts)
  await monitorRequests.waitForAllRequests();

  // screenshot page with new content
  await pageElement.screenshot({
    type: "jpeg",
    quality: 100
  });

} // END LOOP

// close
await browser.close();
```

## NPM Module

```
class PuppeteerNetworkMonitor {

    constructor(page) {
        this.promisees = [];
        this.page = page;
        this.resourceType = ['image'];
        this.pendingRequests = new Set();
        this.finishedRequestsWithSuccess = new Set();
        this.finishedRequestsWithErrors = new Set();
        page.on('request', (request) => {
            request.continue();
            if (this.resourceType.includes(request.resourceType())) {
                this.pendingRequests.add(request);
                this.promisees.push(
                    new Promise(resolve => {
                        request.resolver = resolve;
                    }),
                );
            }
        });
        page.on('requestfailed', (request) => {
            if (this.resourceType.includes(request.resourceType())) {
                this.pendingRequests.delete(request);
                this.finishedRequestsWithErrors.add(request);
                if (request.resolver) {
                    request.resolver();
                    delete request.resolver;
                }
            }
        });
        page.on('requestfinished', (request) => {
            if (this.resourceType.includes(request.resourceType())) {
                this.pendingRequests.delete(request);
                this.finishedRequestsWithSuccess.add(request);
                if (request.resolver) {
                    request.resolver();
                    delete request.resolver;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    async waitForAllRequests() {
        if (this.pendingRequestCount() === 0) {
            return;
        }
        await Promise.all(this.promisees);
    }

    pendingRequestCount() {
        return this.pendingRequests.size;
    }
}

module.exports = PuppeteerNetworkMonitor;
```

Comment: Could you share your code, I need to do the same thing with images for my project

Comment: Which bit do you need? The modified NPM module or the code to loop through images on your page?

Comment: The modified npm module.

Comment: I also found this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672650/2179289 ,so I'm wondering how your solution differs

Comment: I see. My solution is different because I have to change the images on the page after the page has finished loading, with an XHR request. That link you posted was something I tried previously, but I could get it to work with my use case (not to say it wouldn't work for you).

Comment: I too am doing a xhr request so I guess I'll need your solution to detect when the images are loaded.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the modified NPM module code.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still interested in the solution [@danlong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784701/7011003) posted above but wants it in a more modern way, here is the TypeScript version for it:

```
import { HTTPRequest, Page, ResourceType } from "puppeteer";

export class PuppeteerNetworkMonitor {
    page: Page;
    resourceType: ResourceType[] = [];
    promises: Promise<unknown>[] = [];
    pendingRequests = new Set();
    finishedRequestsWithSuccess = new Set();
    finishedRequestsWithErrors = new Set();
    constructor(page: Page, resourceType: ResourceType[]) {
        this.page = page;
        this.resourceType = resourceType;
        this.finishedRequestsWithSuccess = new Set();
        this.finishedRequestsWithErrors = new Set();
        page.on(
            "request",
            async (
                request: HTTPRequest & { resolver?: (value?: unknown) => void },
            ) => {
                await request.continue();
                if (this.resourceType.includes(request.resourceType())) {
                    this.pendingRequests.add(request);
                    this.promises.push(
                        new Promise((resolve) => {
                            request.resolver = resolve;
                        }),
                    );
                }
            },
        );
        page.on(
            "requestfailed",
            (request: HTTPRequest & { resolver?: (value?: unknown) => void }) => {
                if (this.resourceType.includes(request.resourceType())) {
                    this.pendingRequests.delete(request);
                    this.finishedRequestsWithErrors.add(request);
                    if (request.resolver) {
                        request.resolver();
                        delete request.resolver;
                    }
                }
            },
        );
        page.on(
            "requestfinished",
            (request: HTTPRequest & { resolver?: (value?: unknown) => void }) => {
                if (this.resourceType.includes(request.resourceType())) {
                    this.pendingRequests.delete(request);
                    this.finishedRequestsWithSuccess.add(request);
                    if (request.resolver) {
                        request.resolver();
                        delete request.resolver;
                    }
                }
            },
        );
    }

    async waitForAllRequests() {
        if (this.pendingRequestCount() === 0) {
            return;
        }
        await Promise.all(this.promises);
    }

    pendingRequestCount() {
        return this.pendingRequests.size;
    }
}
```

I did change one thing, where instead of hard-coding what resource type to look for in the network requests, I am passing the resource types to look for as one of the constructor arguments. That should make this class more generic.

I've tested this code with my API that uses Puppeteer, and it works great.
For the usage of this class, it would be similar to what @danlong posted above like this:

```
// other necessary puppeteer code here...
const monitorNetworkRequests = new PuppeteerNetworkMonitor(page, ["image"]);
await monitorNetworkRequests.waitForAllRequests();
```